# Tkinter displays text with {}

Tags: python, windows, csv, python-3.x, tkinter

**Basic system info:** Windows 7 64 bit, python 3.4.3 64 bit, and running in PyCharm Educational edition 1.0.1

I wrote a program that displays a window, with a drop menu and a button, to the user (example near the end). The drop menu has a list of bicycle ID numbers that the user can choose from, then click the button and text will be displayed telling the user what bike they chose and how many times it was ridden. This is the code:

```
1    from tkinter import *
2    import pandas as pd
3    from tkinter import ttk
4    from collections import OrderedDict
5
6    # read in the sorted bike file
7    data = pd.read_csv('Sorted_Bike_Uses.csv', header=0)
8
9    bike = data['Bike ID']                    # put the bike id's into a series
10    bike = bike.tolist()                      # make the series a list
11    uses = data['Number of Uses']             # put the number of uses into a series
12    uses = uses.tolist()                      # make the series a list
13    a = OrderedDict(list(zip(bike, uses)))    # put the bike ids ans uses into a dictionary, preserving their order
14    bike.sort()                               # sort the bike id's for the drop down list
15
16
17    # this function updates the text displayed on the box
18    def select():
19        sf = "Bicycle #%s" % var.get()
20        root.title(sf)
21        x = int("%s" % var.get())
22        display.configure(text=("Bicycle", x, "was used", a[x], "times."))
23        display.pack()
24
25    # sets up the window
26    root = Tk()
27    root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (330, 80, 200, 150))
28    root.title("Optionmenu as combobox")
29
30    # sets up how it will display the information
31    display = Label(root, text="")
32
33    # starts the drop down box at 14529
34    var = StringVar(root)
35    var.set('14529')
36
37    # sets up the drop down list
38    w = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=var, values=bike)
39    w.pack()
40
41    # sets up the button used to select a bike id
42    button = Button(root, text='Analyze!', command=select)
43    button.pack(side='left', padx=20, pady=10)
44
45    root.mainloop()
```

The problem is that when a bike id is chosen the output text has {} added in around "was used". For example:

[image]

I can't figure out why they are there or how to remove them. It is not really a huge issue, but i would like more uniform formatting.

Also a second issue is that when I go to chose a different bike id, the options have comma's included in the numbers. So if I first choose 14529, like in the above example, and then I choose 14530, 14530 will look like "14530,". That causes the program to not work unless I delete the comma before hitting the button. Again, the program will work as long as I remove the comma, but I would like to figure out how I can fix that.

Comment: Why don't you pass a single string as text - `text='Bicycle {} was used {} times'.format(x, a[x])`?

Comment: Well that was the quickest answer I've had ever. I didn't know about that option. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The curly braces there are a little bit of Tcl leaking through. You have passed a Python list to set the display in this line:

```
display.configure(text=("Bicycle", x, "was used", a[x], "times."))
```

This is being converted into a Tcl list when applied to the Tk widget and in Tcl a list element with a space in it gets shown with curly brace quoting.

As pointed out by @jonrsharpe you should set the label text to be a string to avoid this.